exceptionLogging is not a valid field in manifest for alternate runtime add-on
Problem
We have a Gmail add-on that's written using an alternate runtime.
Recently, a handful of our clients started getting "Something went wrong when executing the add-on." errors.  According to the docs this error should appear in my GCP log explorer, however:  My log explorer is 100% empty.
What I've tried
A little searching, and I find a doc saying that I may need "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER", in my manifest.  I check, indeed it's missing, so I try to add it but:

And the deployment refuses to save (There was an error editing the deployment: the provided deployment is invalid.)
Questions
How can I get logging, particularly error logging, working in my alternate runtime add-on?
Do alternate runtimes use a different schema for their manifest?  Is this field even necessary, is STACKDRIVER used when no value is provided?

I was (until your question) unfamiliar with this mechanism and it's neat. I suspect (!?) that you will need to use the relevant Cloud Logging SDK and write logs to it in order that your alternate runtime (unless this is also running on Google Cloud?) can write to Cloud Logging. Please update your question with more specifics: runtime, language etc. and I'll try to provide an Answer. I just tried creating a Workspace addon and was able to log to Cloud Logging. Alternatively, if you prefer another logging system, you could write to that .

@DazWilkin The alternate runtime isn't really a different way of drawing the UI, it's just a way you can generate add-on JSON on your own servers dynamically.
In this case, I have a button that (when pressed) causes the add-on to crash and show the "Something went wrong..." message.  This error is entirely after Google has received the formed JSON from my server, and does not report back to my server.
I'm not sure that additional logging on my server will help.

@DazWilkin RE: "I just tried creating a Workspace addon and was able to log to Cloud Logging."  Out of curiosity, did your manifest come with, or can you add "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"?

No exceptionLogging isn't permitted for HTTP manifests.

@DazWilkin ahhh - is this documented somewhere?  I couldn't find it.

I created a homepageTrigger.runFuction (and a gmail.contextualTriggers.onTriggerFunction) in both of these I have log statements that use Cloud Logging (because my add-on is running locally) and I'm able to capture the logs in Cloud Logging.

The documentation is..... sub-optimal.... Manifests: http

I am also able to find a single NOTICE log entry against protoPayload.serviceName="gsuiteaddons.googleapis.com". It's in cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity but these correspond to Deployments.

One other thing: my very basic addon generates the minimal JSON response and so I too receive errors in the add-on page but these aren't logged to Cloud Logging. The only way I'm able to understand that there's a problem is because my add-on logs errors.

@DazWilkin yeah, I think that's about where I am right now.  I know there is an error, but I can't see what it is (bonus points: it's only in prod)

Where is your addon running? If it's running on e.g. Cloud Run you should see any output to stderr|stdout written to the Cloud Run logs.

@DazWilkin It's a Java/Micronaut server that lives off on an AWS box.  We have logging on those servers, but short of printing out every add-on JSON blob we send out, I'm not sure what I can glean from that.

This Workspace Addon service is new to me but... if your backend captures any metadata for your users, you could "glean" (good word!) the logs of users seeing issues and, at least, focus the effort.Yes, your addon service adheres to Google's API but, is it not possible that there's an issue with your service that's causing it to not generate the correct responses in these situations?

I assume you're also familiar with the Metrics page which includes "Errors by API method"? https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gsuiteaddons.googleapis.com/metrics?project={PROJECT}

@DazWilkin oh totally - we already have user IDs to check against (problem is 100% repro in prod, so I can just trigger it myself and look for my user).  As far as I can tell the JSON is leaving our server in good shape.

@DazWilkin RE: "Errors by API method" - yeah, checked that too.  Are you getting anything on your demo app there?

No errors but I do not expect any because I'm not using e.g. OAuth in my basic addon and the others correspond to deployment/install/uninstall etc. which work.
